# Spring Boot MongoDB Repositories in other Module Are not @Autowired

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, maven, spring-data, spring-boot

I am trying to separate my Main/Web Application from the Data layer by creating separate Eclipse modules. When running the main application project, spring boot complains:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: it.vertyze.platform.data.models.LocationRepository it.vertyze.platform.web.main.Application.locationRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.vertyze.platform.data.models.LocationRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at it.vertyze.platform.web.main.Application.main(Application.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: it.vertyze.platform.data.models.LocationRepository it.vertyze.platform.web.main.Application.locationRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.vertyze.platform.data.models.LocationRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [it.vertyze.platform.data.models.LocationRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:494)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

My Main Application is here:

```
package it.vertyze.platform.web.main;

import it.vertyze.platform.data.models.LocationRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;

 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @EnableMongoRepositories
 @Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
 public class Application {

    @Autowired
    LocationRepository locationRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And my LocationRepository is in a different Package in a different Module:

```
package it.vertyze.platform.data.models;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "location", path = "location")
public interface LocationRepository extends MongoRepository<Location, String> {

    List<Location> findByLocationIdentifier(@Param("locationIdentifier") String locationIdentifier);

}
```

For Sake of completeness, here is the code for the Entity I would like to store:

```
package it.vertyze.platform.data.models;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Location{
    @Id 
    private String id;

    private String locationName;
    private String locationIdentifier;
    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }
    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }
    public String getLocationIdentifier() {
        return locationIdentifier;
    }
    public void setLocationIdentifier(String locationIdentifier) {
        this.locationIdentifier = locationIdentifier;
    }
}
```

Any help? I figured this would be quite common a thing to do. Yet maybe I'm just too new to Spring then.

Comment: You aren't scanning the package containing the repositories. A `@ComponentScan` without additional config takes the current package as the starting point. I suggest moving the application class to the `it.vertyze.platform` package or put it in the component-scan `@ComponentScan("it.vertyze.platform")`. You should be able to remove the `@EnableMongoRepositories` and `@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)` as Spring Boot takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks! I did put the package into the annotation after asking the question... Stupid me did not realize that that package actually has to exist...

Answer (score 0):

M. Deinums comment did it. Sorry for bothering Stackoverflow. Turned out I was too stupid to put a parent package with my main method in my trunk